# Joystick/Gamepad events not emitted?

Tags: android, android-ndk, joystick, gamepad

Using the NDK, I can't get any motion event source neither from gamepad nor from joystick through usb (didn't test on bluetooth): usb keyboard or usb mouse work well and the xbox controller is recognized by some app: "Game Controller Tester" sees it: I'm using rust and the crate ndk, but this doesn't seem to be an issue.

I handle InputEvent through winit, touch events are correctly handled from touch screen, but no event from connected gamepad/joystick is shown.

Comment: Which gamepads/joysticks did you test with? Which axes does Game Controller Tester see?

Comment: I use a said XBox360  compatible controller : Game Controller Tester sees all axes (L and R) and responds to buttons. From now I'm asking for usb permissions , and get them granted for the controller; meanwhile , I still don't get any event from the controller..